# How to install Eclipse C++ IDE in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I would like to install the latest eclipse C++ IDE on Ubuntu 16.04.
I tried by

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++
```

But unfortunately this installs the old version.

I also looked by installing from Ubuntu software center, failed by installing the old eclipse version. I am left with the option of downloading the bundle from official site. However, the download is very slow.

Would be happy to know the installation of latest version.

Comment: Had the same problem. Install it from the official website: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

Download the debian or tar.gz package from the original site and click two times on it to install, now in latest ubuntu it should auto-detect it as an installation package.
For your internet speed We can't do nothing, or you just wait the time it just needs to download it or you try to install the linux download from Official website.
Are you using facebook/skype/ p2p or torrent programs? they slowdown a lot your internet speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download the cdt files from here :

```
 https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse-cdt/8.6.0-1
```

Extract & launch the binary eclipse ( eclipse& )

This should help

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt install -y eclipse-cdt-*
```

More details [here](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/09/17/ubuntu-1604-eclipse-cdt-en/).

Answer (score 0):

Do not install eclipse from with sudo apt-get (as of Oct 13th 2017).  It will get you the old version, which will clash with the new 3.4.7 version if you install that.  Gave me too much headache.  Download the tar.gz of the new version online, then run the installer from the unpacked folder.